# User control repainting only when window moved

Tags: c#, winforms, repaint, invalidation

I have a custom user control which displays waveform of an audio file. I've put two instances of controls on a form. The second instance works as expected while the first instance causes the problem mentioned.

What I am doing is drawing a vertical (red) line, indicating current position. The problem is best seen in a [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_X0JbcxZrSE).

This is the code of my custom controller (OnPaint() - notice  that I invalidate only the region affected by the red vertical line):

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    [...]
    Invalidate(new Rectangle(x_pos-5, 0, x_pos, this.Height));
    using (Pen linePen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1.5f))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(linePen, x_pos, 0, x_pos, this.Height);
        Invalidate(new Rectangle(x_pos-2,0,x_pos+2,this.Height));
    }

    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

---

Q: Since the OnPaint method is equivalent for both controls why do I need to move the window to repaint the first control (waveform)?

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: Winforms. Forgot to mention it. Also updated the post - the question is at the end.

Comment: You should add a `Timer` and invalidate your form whenever the `Timer` ticks (add an `OnTick` event to the `Timer`). Don't forget to set your `Timer`'s period appropriately. You surely want to update your form more than just once every 5 seconds, right?

Comment: So by default the form repaints only every 5 seconds? Didn't know that.

Comment: No, the `OnPaint` event of the form is only called, when the form needs to be repainted, that is when the window is moved or resized or when another window is being moved over your form. That's why you need a `Timer` (PS: I see the `Timer`'s default period is 100 ms, so you don't actually need to change that, if you don't want to)

Comment: repaint is called every 5 seconds? I don't think it is true. Any references? Thanks.

Comment: @David The 5 seconds were just an example. The default value is 100 milliseconds http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `OnPaint` is that it's only called when it's necessary, for example when the window is moved, resized, after it's brought back from minimized state, or when another window is moved on top of it.

In order to periodically repaint the window (or parts of it), you'll need to add a `Timer` to the form and implement its `Tick` event.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Invalidate();
}
```

By default, `Timer.Interval` is set to `100` (100 ms). If you only want to update your rectangle every second, you can increase that value to `1000` if you want.